# Convert Ext4 partition to an exsisting Btrfs volume

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs

I recently installed Fedora on my laptop and I have my old `/home` ext4 partition (`/dev/sdb2`).
I would like to convert then merge this partition with the btrfs filesystem.

Here is my current setup :

```
$: btrfs filesystem show
Label: 'fedora'  uuid: accd2db4-87ca-4c78-84b9-4500534d63f5
    Total devices 2 FS bytes used 7.76GiB
    devid    1 size 236.89GiB used 1.02GiB path /dev/sda3
    devid    2 size 500.00GiB used 9.01GiB path /dev/sdb1


$: sudo btrfs subvolume list /
ID 256 gen 1007 top level 5 path root
ID 257 gen 1007 top level 5 path home
ID 258 gen 888 top level 256 path var/lib/machines


$: parted -l
...

Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   File system  Name         Flags
 1      1049kB  537GB   537GB  btrfs
 2      537GB   1000GB  463GB  ext4         Linux /home  linux-home
```

As a result I would have a single Btrfs volume (Label: fedora), containing the /dev/sdb2 partition data.

I've found [this](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3) article to convert an Ext partition to Btrfs, but I don't know if it's possible merge two Btrfs volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- move the files
- delete the second partition
- extend the first partition
- extend the filesystem

Comment: Okay @GeraldSchneider, according to you, it's not possible to leave the data in place using btrfs-convert in my case ?

Comment: Well, it would, if you convert the filesystem (which I would never even consider in a production environment). But what do you gain? You will still have two partitions.

Comment: Okay thanks, should I rebalance the data on the disks after this process ? My drives are SSD